# My rest-assured code not work after moving to JDK 17

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, rest-assured

I recently upgraded my project from Java 11 to 17. Somehow my unit tests are failing. They are failing on Initialisation step when I am trying to get a authentication token for my test.

**Code:**

```
Response response = expect().that().statusCode(200)
                .given()
                .body(body)
                .contentType(ContentType.URLENC)
                .baseUri(tokenUrl)
                .when()
                .post()
                .then()
                .extract()
                .response();
```

**build.gradle:**

```
test {
    description = "Runs unit tests"
    group = 'Delivery pipeline'
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.test.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    failFast = true
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
}
```

**Exception:**
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.InputStream.available()" because "is" is null
at java.base/jdk.internal.icu.impl.ICUBinary.getRequiredData(ICUBinary.java:94)
at java.base/jdk.internal.icu.impl.NormalizerImpl.load(NormalizerImpl.java:431)
at java.base/jdk.internal.icu.impl.Norm2AllModes$Norm2AllModesSingleton.(Norm2AllModes.java:274)
at java.base/jdk.internal.icu.impl.Norm2AllModes$NFCSingleton.(Norm2AllModes.java:286)
at java.base/jdk.internal.icu.impl.Norm2AllModes.getNFCInstance(Norm2AllModes.java:259)
at java.base/jdk.internal.icu.text.Normalizer2.getNFCInstance(Normalizer2.java:91)
at java.base/jdk.internal.icu.text.NormalizerBase$NFCModeImpl.(NormalizerBase.java:185)
... 240 more
Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.InputStream.available()" because "is" is null]

I am using latest version of rest assured version 5.3.0. I tried to add groovy 4.0.9 to the gradle, but still no luck.